# Can not extract the results when using cgo call and run numpy matrix dot operation of python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, go, cgo

I dont know the type of resut, thus I dont know how to extact the values in `result` and export it to the go array. Below is the code, which can be compiled and run.

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lm
#cgo pkg-config: python3
#include <Python.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/DataDog/go-python3"
)

func main() {
    python3.Py_Initialize()
    numpy := python3.PyImport_ImportModule("numpy")
    dotFunc := numpy.GetAttrString("dot")

    array1 := python3.PyList_New(2)
    python3.PyList_SetItem(array1, 0, python3.PyList_New(2))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(array1, 1, python3.PyList_New(2))

    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array1, 0), 0, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(1.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array1, 0), 1, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(2.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array1, 1), 0, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(3.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array1, 1), 1, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(4.0))

    array2 := python3.PyList_New(2)
    python3.PyList_SetItem(array2, 0, python3.PyList_New(2))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(array2, 1, python3.PyList_New(2))

    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array2, 0), 0, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(5.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array2, 0), 1, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(6.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array2, 1), 0, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(7.0))
    python3.PyList_SetItem(python3.PyList_GetItem(array2, 1), 1, python3.PyFloat_FromDouble(8.0))

    result := dotFunc.CallFunctionObjArgs(array1, array2)
    fmt.Println(array1)
    fmt.Println(array2)
    fmt.Println(result)

    fmt.Println(python3.PyList_Size(array1))       //return 2
    fmt.Println(python3.PyList_Size(array2))       //retunr 2
    fmt.Println(python3.PyType_CheckExact(result)) //return false, does not know its type

}
```

**Updated based on the first answer** (also I clean up the codes to avoid importing go-python3), I should convert numpy array to c array:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -I/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lm -L/anaconda3/lib -lpython3.7m
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize the Python interpreter
    C.Py_Initialize()
    numpyModule := C.PyImport_ImportModule(C.CString("numpy"))
    dotFunc := C.PyObject_GetAttrString(numpyModule, C.CString("dot"))

    array1 := C.PyList_New(2)
    C.PyList_SetItem(array1, 0, C.PyList_New(2))
    C.PyList_SetItem(array1, 1, C.PyList_New(2))

    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array1, 0), 0, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(1.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array1, 0), 1, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(2.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array1, 1), 0, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(3.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array1, 1), 1, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(4.0))

    array2 := C.PyList_New(2)
    C.PyList_SetItem(array2, 0, C.PyList_New(2))
    C.PyList_SetItem(array2, 1, C.PyList_New(2))

    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array2, 0), 0, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(5.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array2, 0), 1, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(6.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array2, 1), 0, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(7.0))
    C.PyList_SetItem(C.PyList_GetItem(array2, 1), 1, C.PyFloat_FromDouble(8.0))

    args := C.PyTuple_New(2)
    C.PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, array1)
    C.PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, array2)

    result := C.PyObject_CallObject(dotFunc, args) // return np.array

    result = (*C.double)(C.PyArray_DATA(result)) // np.array to c array

    fmt.Println(result)

    C.Py_Finalize()
}
```

The only problem now is: `go build` return error `could not determine kind of name for C.PyArray_DATA`. So I missing something in  CFLAGS, LDFLAGS or other place?

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, cannot be of much help as the package providing the Python3 bridge in your example [does not work with Python ≥ 3.7](https://github.com/DataDog/go-python3/issues/38), its blessed fork [does not, either](https://github.com/go-python/cpy3/issues/1), and even my Debian system already has 3.11, so the packages simply do not build on my system. Still, I'll try to offer a possible path forward.

If you load up `numpy` in a `python3` session and see the docs on `numpy.dot` –

```
>>> import numpy
>>> help(numpy.dot)
```

…you will notice it's documented to return a value of a custom type, provided by `numpy`–a `numpy.ndarray`, and all custom types in Python are inherently classes. You can read up on that type using `help(numpy.ndarray)`.

Given this information, we can simply approach the value returned by the call of interest using the "stock" Python's protocol of working with objects (instances of classes): you can query any object about its type, the attributes it supports, call methods on it and so on, and the package you're using [implements the necessary support](https://github.com/DataDog/go-python3/blob/master/object.go), which you can see in action in one of the package's examples called "list".

A couple of assorted notes follows.

- Your example does not appear to actually use `cgo`, so I'm not sure it's needed–unless that's some remnant from the real code you're dealing with.
- Quite possibly you don't actually want to produce a Go's *array,* but rather a slice. If you do not know the distinction, start [here](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro), and continue [there](https://go.dev/blog/slices) *before* continuing with your endaevor.
- As you should see from the `numpy.ndarray` documentation, this type is quite a complicated thing as it ostensibly supports arrays of arbitrary dimensions.

  Looks like a way forward is creating a helper function which would take an `*python3.PyObject`, verify it has the expected type, verify it has the expected dimensions and then extract the data–supposedly using the `__index__()` method of the object protocol.
- If you really just want to multiply matrices in Go, and are not actually tasked with interfacing some big existing *well-tested* Python code which makes heavy use of `numpy`, I would recommend to instead use a Go-native solution such as [`gonum`](https://github.com/gonum/gonum) which supports dot product in its [package `mat`](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat).
  This package provides implementations written in assembly for `amd64`, so the performance on comparable datasets should at least be on par with Python code using `numpy` and the end result will be *much* easier to support and ship.